# What is the effect of changing the volume of a permanent magnet in the vicinity of an electromagnet?

Tags: electromagnetism, superposition

If I have a single Neodimium permanent magnet, held at a fixed distance (gap distance) from the end of an energised coil, what would be the effect of adding a second magnet to the back side of the first?

Would it be a delta equivalent to moving the original magnet to the position of the second magnet, or would permeability increase the effectiveness of the second magnet?

Visualising the problem, assuming the electromagnet is the same in each case with the same current flowing:

Would we expect force $F_2 = F_1 + F_3$ ?

[image: Visualisation of problem.]

Comment: What does "delta equivalent" mean?

Comment: Just to say, would the additional force (force delta), be equal to the force resulting from just having the second magnet by itself in the system.